# When i try to run the following code to open an image

Tags: opencv, python

import matplotlib.
matplotlib.use('TkAgg').
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt.
from PIL import Image.
pic =Image.open('User/XYZ/Downloads/DATA/XYZ.jpg')

I get this error.

fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb").
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'User/XYZ/Downloads/DATA/XYZ.jpg'

Comment: Is there some reason why you don't believe Python when it says "no such file or directory"?  I suspect there should actually be a leading slash on that pathname.

Comment: Please format your code it makes it easier for others to read.